# How do I create a plugin to create and save multiple entries from one front-end form?

Tags: plugin-development

I need to create several entries in different channels from a single front-end form. I realise that to do this I will need to create a plugin to handle the request.

Can I just to iterate over the post values in my controller action, validate them and build the entry models for each new entry, then loop around Craft's EntryService `saveEntry()` service for each entry I want to save?

Or do I need to write my own `saveEntry()` service to handle saving multiple entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with your first option.

Grab the `$_POST` values via [craft()->request->getPost()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getPost-detail), assemble them in your multiple [EntryModels](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel), [validate](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#validate-detail) each model, then pass them off to [craft()->entry->saveEntry()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail).